# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime, datatable

I want to retrieve the date from datarow and do the comparison based on the date from datarow. However it have the error stating that String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
[This is the error example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xum6S.png)

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow[] rows = socialEvents.Select(
              String.Format(
                 "Date >= #{0}# AND Date < #{1}#",
                 e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                 e.Day.Date.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()
              )
           );
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image;
            image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();

            image.ToolTip = row["Description"].ToString();

            e.Cell.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
        }
}


 private void BuildSocialEventTable()
    {
        // to simulate a database query
        socialEvents = new DataTable();
        socialEvents.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)));
        socialEvents.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));


        DataRow row;
        row = socialEvents.NewRow();
        row["Date"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
        row["Description"] = "Holiday";

        socialEvents.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: What does your eventargs actually contain? I dont think the error has anything to do with the data table.

Comment: actually the eventargs is getting date from the datable, then use the selected date to make highlight on my calendar. For example, 24/9/2016 retrieve from the datatable, then the date on calendar is highligted become blue. However, the error occur in Select code.

Comment: The calendar control may be bound to data table but that doesn't mean the event args are what you think in the raising if that event. Remove that code, just do e.day.date.toshortdatestring and you will still get the error. Always check data for null and TryParse as appropriate before using.